# Translating source field of pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table where source data headers are written in german. Is there a way to translate data in pivot table in such a way, that I only translate headers in source sheet?

Of course if it was a problem of one table I could do it manually, but I have more than 50 different tables based on the source data.

One idea is to run VBA script to update all the fileds but is there a better solution?

Thank you for any hints

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the Google translate webservice.

Just loop through the headers and then return the English translation.

Comment: Doing so will break whole pivot table so this is definitely something I want to avoid. If it was that simple I would have just translated headers manually, without google translate api

Comment: The only other way to do it would be to add a row above the pivot table range with the translated values and simply hide the other row.

Comment: ... but the headers in pivot table will still point to untranslated headers. Maybe I was not clear - it's not that the headers in source file have to be translated - its what is displayed in pivot table that have to be translated.

Comment: You can manually change the field names in the pivot table by changing the field options.